# Need help sorting a nested array of mix string and integer in specific index

Tags: javascript, sorting, multidimensional-array

I there,

I have a score nested array, which I am trying to sort, however all values are string, and the sorting comes messed-up as expected.

It is also all saved in localstorage.

I have the code below for the sorting which works fine, but only for the first character, so for the index [3] sorting for example I get:

> > 0000, 126, 15, 16, 20, 4, 4, 4, 5, 8 //As you can see in the array below.

But I should get:

> > 0000, 4, 4, 4, 5, 8, 15, 16, 20, 126

I read that I could add zeros prior the sorting, then remove them after the sorting. But I can't figure out a way to add zeros in such a complex data array...

The array looks like this:

```
0: (5) ["Jack 9", "words", "6", "0000", "00:08:21"]
1: (5) ["Jack 6", "words", "59", "126", "00:08:22"]
2: (5) ["Jack 1", "words", "30", "15", "00:03:81"]
3: (5) ["Jack 4", "words", "24", "16", "00:02:94"]
4: (5) ["Jack 2", "words", "9",  "20", "00:14:90"]
5: (5) ["Jack 11","words", "9",   "4", "00:18:04"]
6: (5) ["Jack 10","words", "9",   "4", "00:19:06"]
7: (5) ["Jack 5", "words", "6",   "4", "00:08:97"]
8: (5) ["Jack 8", "words", "9",   "5", "00:16:83"]
9: (5) ["Jack 7", "words", "8",   "8", "00:19:98"]
```

```
function sortScoresErrors(array){
    array.sort((function(index){
        return function(a, b){
            return (a[index] === b[index] ? 0 : (a[index] < b[index] ? -1 : 1));
        };
        })(3));// (3) is the index - Descending
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert the string to ***Number*** in the condition and you are good to go.

Replace `return (a[index] === b[index] ? 0 : (a[index] < b[index] ? -1 : 1));`

to this:     `return (Number(a[index]) === Number(b[index]) ? 0 : (Number(a[index]) < Number(b[index]) ? -1 : 1));`

> This works when the strings in the third index are actually numeric

Comment: Thank you very much for helping! I am learning JS by my own and quite don't understand all its facets. Your answer was genius and simple, I was able to implement it and I now understand how it works. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the value of the wanted index is could be read as numerival value and take another function with the delta of the item to compare.

```js
function sortScoresErrors(array) {
    array.sort((function (index) {
        return isFinite(array[0][index])
            ? (a, b) => a[index] - b[index]
            : (a, b) => (a[index] === b[index] ? 0 : (a[index] < b[index] ? -1 : 1));
    })(3));
}

var data = [["Jack 9", "words", "6", "0000", "00:08:21"], ["Jack 6", "words", "59", "126", "00:08:22"], ["Jack 1", "words", "30", "15", "00:03:81"], ["Jack 4", "words", "24", "16", "00:02:94"], ["Jack 2", "words", "9", "20", "00:14:90"], ["Jack 11", "words", "9", "4", "00:18:04"], ["Jack 10", "words", "9", "4", "00:19:06"], ["Jack 5", "words", "6", "4", "00:08:97"], ["Jack 8", "words", "9", "5", "00:16:83"], ["Jack 7", "words", "8", "8", "00:19:98"]];

sortScoresErrors(data);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi there, Thank you very much for your quite insightful answer, i still trying to understand how it really works, never the less its great to have another point of view. Much appreciated for your time!